# Dplyr R n() group by function to Pandas similar function

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any function in pandas that can 100% replicate the n() function used in dplyr when you are grouping by ?
For instance, having this code:

```
require(dplyr)
gb <- mtcars %>%
      group_by(gear, cyl) %>% 
      summarise(Disp    = sum(disp),
                QSec    = sum(qsec),
                Counter = n())
```

how can I replicate this (and the n() function !) in pandas ?
Nevertheless, query final output should look like the following:

```
   gear   cyl  Disp  QSec Counter
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <int>
1  3.00  4.00   120  20.0       1
2  3.00  6.00   483  39.7       2
3  3.00  8.00  4291 206        12
4  4.00  4.00   821 157         8
5  4.00  6.00   655  70.7       4
6  5.00  4.00   215  33.6       2
7  5.00  6.00   145  15.5       1
8  5.00  8.00   652  29.1       2
```

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by list of tuples - first value is new column name and second is aggregate function:

```
df = df.groupby('gear')['qsec'].agg([('QSec','sum'),('Counter','size')]).reset_index()
```

For `groupby` by multiple columns need `list`:

```
df = df.groupby(['gear', 'vs'])['qsec'].agg([('QSec','sum'),('Counter','size')]).reset_index()
```

EDIT:

```
df = (df.groupby(['gear', 'cyl'])
        .agg({'qsec':'sum', 'disp':'sum', 'gear':'size'})
        .rename(columns={'gear':'Counter', 'disp':'Disp', 'qsec':'QSec'})
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   gear  cyl    QSec  Counter    Disp
0     3    4   20.01        1   120.1
1     3    6   39.66        2   483.0
2     3    8  205.71       12  4291.4
3     4    4  156.90        8   821.0
4     4    6   70.68        4   655.2
5     5    4   33.60        2   215.4
6     5    6   15.50        1   145.0
7     5    8   29.10        2   652.0
```

Comment: Actually, this code creates an Index ! I would like to create no index using 'as_Index = False'...sorry my bad not having said this.

Comment: @AndreaFerrante - No problem, please check edited answer.

Comment: Nice ! thanks buddy. On last quick question: what if I would like to group by more than one column ? In here I am grouping by 'gear column' only...thanks in advance a lot...awesome answer.

Comment: sure,no problem...btw, here we are using only 'qsec column', is there any if I wanted to add a second columns like 'gear' for instance ? Thanks really a lot...

Comment: @AndreaFerrante - Can you add sample data and expected output to question?

Comment: @AndreaFerrante - Then need pass dict to `agg`, check edited answer.

Comment: I am sorry but it is not what I wanted actually: python keeps saying that it cannot manage dplyr 'Counter' column ! if you see closely man, column names between dplyr R code and pandas are not the exact same. Could you please have a look ? Once you can. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreaFerrante - Now is answer edited, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `dplython` to mimic some of the functionalities of `dplyr`

```
out = (mtcars >>
 group_by(X.gear, X.cyl) >>
 mutate(n = 1) >>
 summarize(Disp = X.disp.sum(), QSec = X.qsec.sum(), Counter = X.n.count()))

print(out)
#  gear  cyl  Counter    Disp    QSec
#0     3    4        1   120.1   20.01
#1     3    6        2   483.0   39.66
#2     3    8       12  4291.4  205.71
#3     4    4        8   821.0  156.90
#4     4    6        4   655.2   70.68
#5     5    4        2   215.4   33.60
#6     5    6        1   145.0   15.50
#7     5    8        2   652.0   29.10
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd
from dplython import (DplyFrame, X, diamonds, select, sift, sample_n, 
    sample_frac, head, arrange, mutate, group_by, summarize, DelayFunction) 

file = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv"
mtcars = DplyFrame(pd.read_csv(file))
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry but I need pandas ! Thanks for the idea ;-)

Comment: @AndreaFerrante  It is using `pandas` as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is equivalent way in python using [datar](https://github.com/pwwang/datar)

```py
In [2]: from datar import f
   ...: from datar.datasets import mtcars
   ...: from datar.dplyr import group_by, summarise, n
   ...: from datar.base import sum
   ...: 
   ...: gb = (
   ...:   mtcars >>
   ...:   group_by(f.gear, f.cyl) >>
   ...:   summarise(Disp=sum(f.disp),
   ...:             QSec=sum(f.qsec),
   ...:             Counter=n())
   ...: )
   ...: gb
[2021-04-30 16:54:15][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['gear'] (override with `_groups` argument)
Out[2]: 
   gear  cyl    Disp    QSec  Counter
0     3    4   120.1   20.01        1
1     3    6   483.0   39.66        2
2     3    8  4291.4  205.71       12
3     4    4   821.0  156.90        8
4     4    6   655.2   70.68        4
5     5    4   215.4   33.60        2
6     5    6   145.0   15.50        1
7     5    8   652.0   29.10        2
[Groups: ['gear'] (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues or ask me questions about using it.